# Can't get bathroom light cover off!

Tags: bathroom, light, removal

[image]

We have tried twisting both ways, pulling etc. No screws visiable. Sorry for awful photo, it's pitch black in the bathroom now!

Answer (score 5):

I see what appears to be threads at the top of the cover/diffuser. A counter-clockwise turn should remove it. I also see paint and drywall mud that MAY be preventing you from turning the diffuser.

Comment: Also, I would try to heat it a bit with hair dry fan - this could help against paint (by softening it) which could be on the thread as well.

Answer (score 3):

The glass part should screw off from the metal part.

If it's stuck, try tapping the glass sharply (as hard as you dare!) with the handle of a large screwdriver, or something similar, while you try to twist it.

It might help to wrap something like a leather belt tightly round the glass, to get a grip on it all the way round.

Be careful if it seems like you are unscrewing the metal part from the ceiling. If that starts to happen, there is a chance you will short circuit the wiring inside and trip the breaker on your house lights when you try to switch this one on.

Comment: Better yet, switch the breaker off before starting... and hope a second branch circuit isn't along for a ride in the box.

Comment: Be sure you're wearing good fitting safety glasses/goggles before striking the glass cover or putting  a lot of force on it either by hand or with a strap -- wear leather or other protective gloves if you're going to apply a lot of force with your hands just in case the glass breaks.

Answer (score 2):

Try turning it counter-clockwise instead of clockwise like someone suggested before. Also, try to get the glass of first, and then the rest. It seems like you're just having issues with the ceiling :( If it's stuck, maybe try to push it out with something flat and sharp. Maybe a knife would get it moving?

Comment: Sorry, I should've read alephzero's comment more thoroughly, I didn't realize that I was saying pretty much the exact same thing as him.